# angularjs directive change scope property value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm writing an angularjs directive, and receive properties from html attributes.
Then I created an isolate scope for my directive, and modified the value of the scope properties, but the directive template does not show the modified value.

I created a demo in [`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/7K4S1W5IvjkyFop6yyzI?p=preview).

Can anyone help me changing to template value 'test' to 'changeit'?

**Let me describe my questions more detail:**
I may have a directive and in the html like: , the 'top' is just a simple string, not any ngModel, so I use '@' to receive it in directive, but when I modify it in link, the template model value not change, then I try '=', as it is not an ngModel, so the received value is undefined, but can be dynamic changed in template {{}}.

Answer (score 0):

You are using attribute based linking that is one way. For two way binding use `=` in your directive definition. Something like:

```
scope: {
      title: '=title'
}
```

**Update**: I got your question now. The issue here is that, the `@` based binding keeps the parent scope and the isolated scope in sync. So even if you change the bound variable in the directive, it will be reverted back to the original value. You can verify this by adding a $timeout to the second console log

```
  $timeout(function(){
        console.log(scope.title);  
      })
```

the value of title is reverted back.

The option you have is to copy the title value into a new variable in the link function and bind that function to your template.

Comment: Hi Chandermani, let me describe my question. I may have a directive and in the html like: <div my-dir placement='top'></div>, the 'top' is just a simple string, not any ngModel, so I use '@' to receive it in directive, but when I modify it in link, the template model value not change, then I try '=', as it is not an ngModel, so the received value is undefined, but can be dynamic changed in template {{}}.

Comment: @Awakening please check my upate.

Comment: Yes I also realize it. Only way is to use a new variable for the template, But i really don't like that........Thanks all the time, I will keep this question open, may someone has a better solution